# Retrieve SVN data from File System

Tags: filesystems, svn

One of our virtual machines is down and cannot be restarted. 
Fortunately, I managed to access to the virtual disk file and got all my data back.

I wonder now if there is a way to retrieve the repository files directly from the file system. I have seen replies with `svn admin` but I can't use that here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what do you want exactly, but the `svnadmin dump` dumps the repository and can re-use it everywhere:

```
# dumps the repository
svnadmin dump /path_of/svn/repository > svn.dump
# maybe with compression
svnadmin dump /path_of/svn/repository | bzip2 > svn.dump.bz2
# create repository from file, maybe should create before it
cat svn.dump | svnadmin load /path_of/svn/repository
```

If you want only the files and doesn't need the history, changes, etc., you can checkout:

```
svn checkout file:///path_of/svn/repository /checkout/directory
```

See more the help of [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) and [svn checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html).

Comment: The usual path of svn is /var/svn/<repo_name> on most linux distribution right ?

Comment: I think it's depend on distribution - but maybe yes.

Answer (score 0):

This worked :

```
svn checkout file:///path_of/svn/repository /checkout/directory
```

My repo was located under `/var/svn/`, I extracted it from the virtual machine disk and then proceeded to checkout.